# No funcionan los virtual hosts de Apache en un VPS Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, vps

Tengo un VPS con Ubuntu y Apache2 y no puedo crear hosts virtuales.

Creé el nuevo archivo virtual host apuntando al `/var/www/proyecto`, habilité el sitio con `a2ensite` y luego deshabilité el `000-default.conf` con `a2dissite` (e incluso borré el archivo). Reinicié Apache y ¡nada funciona!.

Mi archivo en `sites-available` se llama `example69.com.conf` y es el siguiente:

[image: captura de pantalla de <code>example69.com.conf</code>]

Dentro de `/var/www/example69.com/public_html/` tengo un archivo `index.html` simplemente.

Y, como bien indica la directiva `DocumentRoot`, tengo el proyecto en `/var/www/example69.com/`, tal como lo muestro a continuación (más que nada por las dudas):

[image: captura de pantalla de un <code>ls</code>]

---

**Edit:
Salidas de lo solicitado en los comentarios:**

```
ls -ltr
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
systemctl status apache2
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
journalctl -xe
```

[image: journalctl -xe]

```
apachectl configtest
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitamos tener acceso a TODOS los archivos de configuración. Ya que has borrado manualmente uno de ellos no sabemos en qué estado ha estado la configuración. También vendría bien un `ls -ltr` del directorio `sites-available` y `sites-enabled` para comprobar los accesos directos que gestiona `a2dissite` y `a2ensite`. Como dices que **no funciona nada**. ¿podrías concretar? ¿arranca el servicio? ¿arranca pero no funciona como esperas? ¿podrías compartir el `error.log`, la salida de `systemctl status apache2` y `journalctl -xe`?

Comment: Como nota de recordatorio además de lo comentado por @OscarGarcia ¿Has revisado los DNS y apuntan a la ip que sirve ese dominio?

Comment: Sería muy útil que compartieras el resultado del comando `apachectl configtest`

Comment: Angelini, por favor, [edita tu pregunta pulsando aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/353585/edit) para agregar la información que te solicitamos (gracias @allexiusw por ese aporte) y déjanos un comentario cuando lo hagas para que estemos notificados. Gracias.

Comment: @OscarGarcia y @OscarR el "no funciona nada" me refería a que todo anda normal. Cuando realizo un un `service apache2 restart` no existen errores, `systemctl status apache2` y `journalctl -xe` todo Ok. Gracias por editarme la pregunta.
Te dejo capturas de lo solicitado.

Comment: @OscarGarcia @allexiusw @OscarR  En en el encabezado de la pregunta dije que había eliminado `000-default.conf`, ahora lo agregue para ganar tiempo y hacer las pruebas pero tampoco obtuve algo positivo.

Comment: Me refería al log de error, `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. También necesito que en tu máquina Windows hagas un `nslookup example69.com` y que nos digas la URL que tratas de cargar y si la has agregado manualmente al archivo `hosts` o algo similar.

Comment: @OscarGarcia si hago un `nslookup example69.com` no la resuelve, ya que dice 'UnKnown no encuentra example69.com: Non-existent domain'. Segundo al archivo hosts no he agregado nada manualmente. Arriba dejare el .log que solicitas.

Comment: Falta que respondas a la pregunta más importante de todas: ¿qué URL intentas cargar en el navegador y qué error o problema te da? (Por favor, que no diga `http://example69.com`, por favor! ).